# Can IIS Express be forced to present an authentication dialog with every new browser session?

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

For our local tests of our intranet application we use IIS Express. Normally when I browse to the local port, I get automatically logged in under my current user account, (Windows credentials). Can I setup IIS Express in a way that it will always ask for credentials whenever I start a new browser session?

Comment: Why? A dialog looks more secure?

Comment: What you see is browser behaviour, and not IIS express behaviour. You can try if this helps (long page with options for various browsers to configure the login process): http://www.lansweeper.com/kb/141/enabling-or-disabling-login-prompts.html

Comment: @LexLi nothing to do with security, just doing multiple role testing with different test users that have different roles assigned through AD groups.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos I don't agree with the other comment as it involves both browser/server sides. There is no easy way to trigger the prompt for the first login, but you can let the first user to switch to another account by sending 401 from server side to browser (something in your web app, to emulate apps such as SharePoint).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Peter B, it is (partly) an Internet Explorer settings. I managed to set the IE settings through the registry by setting the following key:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1]
"1A00"=dword:00010000
```

Now a authentication dialog will pop up each time a page is requested from the localhost.